# CRM Online 2015 Authentication Raw Soap

Tags: authentication, soap, dynamics-crm, adfs, dynamics-crm-online

Hi and thanks for taking this time to look,

I've recently been asked to investigate integration using CRM Online 2015, I've come across some issues trying to Authenticate using Raw SOAP requests.

While I know there's other ways to authenticate, predominantly the using the CRM SDK, my iron will is pushing me to find a solution using Raw SOAP.

I came across a very helpful blog by Jason Lattimer: http://jlattimer.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-c.html

Following this sample, I successfully authenticated with a Trial CRM account using RAW SOAP... Great... Done... I was wrong.

As soon as I pointed this sample at the CRM development environment I got a SOAP error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wst="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust" xmlns:psf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault">
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault>
            <S:Code>
                <S:Value>S:Sender</S:Value> 
                <S:Subcode>
                    <S:Value>wst:FailedAuthentication</S:Value> 
                </S:Subcode>
            </S:Code>
            <S:Reason>
                <S:Text xml:lang="en-US">Authentication Failure</S:Text> 
            </S:Reason>
            <S:Detail>
                <psf:error>
                    <psf:value>0x80048821</psf:value> 
                    <psf:internalerror>
                        <psf:code>0x80047860</psf:code> 
                        <psf:text>Direct login to WLID is not allowed for this federated namespace</psf:text> 
                    </psf:internalerror>
                </psf:error>
            </S:Detail>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The only difference I can think between the Trial version which worked and the development environment is that the development environment setup uses ADFS / AD On-Premises.

Fiddler logs show that Jason's Sample goes straight to login.microsoftonline.com whereas CRM SDK (which works) goes to dynamicscrmemea.accesscontrol.windows.net.

So I believe this is the problem area!

I've been around in circles on stack overflow/other sources, I have a feeling it will a relatively small change required to the SOAP request but I've reached the point where I need some fresh eyes/advice.

Has anyone had experience with this setup? Can anyone gently push me in the right direction?

Many Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

We experienced a similar issue, attempting to create a BizTalk integration.  Eventually we resolved the issue by using a Windows Live/Office 365 account to actually connect with, rather than one that authenticated against the actual AD.  CRM determines authentication types by User, not by org, so you can mix and match...